# Programmatic way of @JsonSubTypes and @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have the following class and it works as expected:

```
class TestClass
{
    @Inject
    public TestClass(
            String type,
            @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
            @JsonSubTypes(value = {
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = "expression"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = List.class, name = "simple")
            })
            Object value)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to use an enum to map the values so I did the following:

```
class TestClass
{
    @Inject
    public TestClass(
            String type,
            @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
            @JsonSubTypes(value = {
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = MyEnum.EXPRESSION),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = List.class, name = MyEnum.SIMPLE)
            })
            Object value)
    {
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because MyEnum is not a String and the annotation values must be constant so I can't dynamically may an enum. Ideally, I will parse the value of `type` field into `MyEnum` and will map the subtypes based on the value of the type.

Comment: perhaps `MyEnum.EXPRESSION.toString()`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher The problem is not just the type difference, `MyEnum.EXPRESSION.toString()` is not constant and that code does not compile.